# A little confused about var app= express()

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I've been reading through the docs but still don't quite understand why we store express() inside an app variable.

I know we can't just call methods using express().get and .post because I tried and failed, but why?

How come it doesn't work like if we would call a function from the module.exports of any file we require?

I'm just really confused lol.

Comment: Each time you call `express()` you get a new object. You need to call it once and save the object so you can reuse it in all your operations.

Comment: So it works as if it is a class and I am calling it with the new keyword?

Comment: Yeah, pretty much.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`express` expects you to create an *instance* object of it and use that. A short way of answering is to say "because that's what the makers of express expect from their users."

Across your script the expectation from the developers is that your `.get` and `.post` methods are called against a common instance of express. In this way, we can say that the call to `express()` initializes the instance and returns an object, which you store in `app`.

Edit in response to your comment:

> *express is a function that creates a new object based off a class*

`express()` initializes the app object and I have not yet encountered a situation where I need to know specifically how. I have no idea if it's a function or a class. This is "encapsulation", the concept in OOP where there is a clear boundary between what you, the user of a module need to know in order to use it, and what the developer of the module needs to know to keep it working.

> *...dependent on the method used(ex: .get), and then uses that instance to allow us to make a route that returns things such as the req and res parameters in the callback?*

The initialized object implements methods, callbacks, et al (like `.get` as you describe.)

> *All of which is in the express module?*

All of which is the conventional pattern for working with the express API.

Comment: So the gist of what I'm getting from everyone is; express is a function that creates a new object based off a class, dependent on the method used(ex: .get), and then uses that instance to allow us to make a route that returns things such as the req and res parameters in the callback? All of which is in the express module?

Answer (score 1):

What really happens when your code call `var express = require('express')`, it actually imports the **Factory Method** called `createApplication` (source code [here](https://github.com/expressjs/express/blob/dc538f6e810bd462c98ee7e6aae24c64d4b1da93/lib/express.js#L28)).

Meanwhile, when you do `express().get` and `express().post`, you're expecting that it will return the same instance of express app object, while it's not. Your code will work if express is using **Singleton** pattern under the hood (resulting in the same instance being returned on every call to `express()`). While the **Factory Method** design pattern will always create a new instance.

That said, every route you add directly using `express().get` or `express().post` will always be spread across many different application instance. So basically, it will work as advertised, but not as you expected to be.

Comment: Ill have to read into the factory method. Thank you though for this post as it will point me in a direction that will help me further my abilities, thanks!